# Photoshop gradient selection too small

Tags: gradient, photoshop

Please help guys, I cant figure out why my gradient selection tool is too small. how can i resize it to its orignal state thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. In Photoshop 
Windows -> workspace -> reset Essential